# Program built using Unity3D Freezing PC - Sporadic

Tags: loops, memory, system, unity-game-engine, freeze

My program that I built using `Unity3D` sporadically freezes, and this action freezes my computer. I'm unable to pinpoint the root cause. I had placed logs all over my project, but the game failed to freeze.

Has any `Unity3D` developer experience their apps sporadically freeze in the manner in which I am describing? Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Due to a 30K character limit, the below object has been modified slightly. This is the object I believe contains a flaw, but I am unable to identify this flaw.

```
public class gamePlayController : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () { 
        int i = 0;
        int selectedPlayers = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalPlayers");

        foreach( GameObject touchable in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Touchable") )
        {   
            touchable.SetActive(false);
            touchable.AddComponent(typeof(PlayerCollisionDispatcher));
            PlayerCollisionDispatcher nextDispatcher = touchable.GetComponent<PlayerCollisionDispatcher>();
            nextDispatcher.currentGameObject = touchable;
            nextDispatcher.gameObject.AddComponent("AudioSource");

            for(i = 0; i < this.m_Players.Count; i++)
            {
                if(string.Compare(touchable.name, this.m_Players[i].name) < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(i < this.m_Players.Count)
            {
                this.m_Players.Insert(i, touchable);
            }
            else
            {
                this.m_Players.Add(touchable);
            }
        }

        while(this.m_Players.Count > selectedPlayers)
        {
            this.m_Players.RemoveRange(selectedPlayers, this.m_Players.Count - selectedPlayers);
        }   

        this.restartGame();
    }

    void OnGameTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Update() {
        Vector3 vector = m_ArialCamera.camera.transform.position;

        vector.x = Mathf.Abs((1500 * this.m_ArialView.x) - 1500) + 250;
            vector.y = (600 * this.m_ArialView.y) + 100;
            vector.z = (1500 * this.m_ArialView.z) + 250;
            m_ArialCamera.camera.transform.position = vector;

        if(this.m_IsGameOver)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("Replay Screen");
        }
        else if(this.m_SimulateCamera)
        {
            this.SimulateCamera();
        }
        else if(m_AutoPluck)
        {
            this.AutoPluck();
        }
        else if(Time.timeScale != 0.0f && this.m_Dispatcher && this.m_Dispatcher.didObjectStop)
        {
            this.determineTurnOutcome();                                
        }
        else if(Time.timeScale != 0.0f && this.m_Dispatcher && this.m_Dispatcher.didObjectMove)
        {
            this.m_Dispatcher.trackMovementProgress();
        }
        else if(Time.timeScale != 0.0f && this.m_Dispatcher 
            && this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].rigidbody.velocity.magnitude > 15.0f 
            && this.m_Dispatcher.didPluck)
        {
            this.m_Dispatcher.didObjectMove = true;
        }
    }

    void restartGame()
    {
        this.m_PlayerIndex = -1;
        foreach( GameObject touchable in this.m_Players)
        {
            GameObject startField = GameObject.FindWithTag ("StartField");      
                    touchable.SetActive(false);
            touchable.rigidbody.useGravity = false;
            touchable.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            touchable.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.zero);
            touchable.rigidbody.AddTorque(Vector3.zero);

            if(startField)
            {
                Vector3 nextPoint = startField.renderer.bounds.center;
                nextPoint.y = 11.0f;
                touchable.transform.position = nextPoint;
            }

            touchable.rigidbody.useGravity = true;
        }
        this.startNextPlayer();
    }

    void startNextPlayer()
    {
        bool isActivePlayerReady = true;        

        do{
            if(this.m_PlayerIndex != -1)
            {
                audioPlayer.PlayAudio("Audio/Next Player");
            }

            this.m_PlayerIndex = (this.m_PlayerIndex + 1)%this.m_Players.Count;
            this.m_Dispatcher = this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].GetComponent<PlayerCollisionDispatcher>();
            if(this.m_Dispatcher && !this.m_Dispatcher.isGameOver && !this.m_Dispatcher.didEnterMud)
            {
                if(!this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].activeSelf)
                {
                    this.m_Dispatcher.startGame();
                    this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].SetActive(true);
                }

                this.m_Dispatcher.startTurn();
            }
        }
        while(!isActivePlayerReady);

        Vector3 vector = this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].transform.position;             
        vector.x = (1500 * this.m_ArialView.x) + 250;
        vector.y = 300;
            vector.z = (1500 * this.m_ArialView.z) + 250;
        m_ArialCamera.camera.transform.position = vector;

        this.setAnnouncement("Player " + this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].name + "'s Turn");

        if(this.m_PlayerIndex != 0)
        {
            this.m_IsSimulating = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SimulatePlayer" + this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].name);
            this.m_IsSimulating = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.m_IsSimulating = 0;
        }   

        GameObject mainCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag ("MainCamera");              
        MouseOrbit mo = null;   
        if(mainCamera)
        {
            mo = mainCamera.GetComponent<MouseOrbit>();
        }   

        if(this.m_IsSimulating >= 1)
        {           
            this.StartSimulation();

            if(mo)
            {
                mo.DoFreeze = true;
            }                   
        }
        else
        {
            if(mo)
            {
                mo.DoFreeze = false;
            }
        }       
    }

    void StartSimulation()
    {
        System.Random random = new System.Random();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int randomNumber = 0;

        //determine either the player object or the next block
        if(this.m_Dispatcher.isKiller)
        {
            m_SimulateToObject = this.m_Players[randomNumber%this.m_Players.Count];                 
            randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0:D2}", this.m_Dispatcher.targetScore);
            Debug.Log("target score=" + sb.ToString());

            foreach(GameObject scoreField in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ScoreField"))
            {
                if(scoreField.name == sb.ToString())
                {
                    m_SimulateToObject = scoreField;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        this.m_IsTargetInitiallyVisible = false;                
        this.m_SimulationTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(TriggerCameraSimulation);
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Interval=2500;
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Enabled=true;
    }

    void TriggerCameraSimulation(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Enabled = false;
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Dispose();
        this.m_SimulateCamera = true;
    }

    void SimulateCamera()
    {
        GameObject mainCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag ("MainCamera");              
        MouseOrbit mo = null;   
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Enabled = false;
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Dispose();

        if(mainCamera)
        {
            mo = mainCamera.GetComponent<MouseOrbit>();

            if(!this.m_IsTargetInitiallyVisible)
            {
                mo.IsManualMove = true;
                mainCamera.transform.position = this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].transform.position;
                mainCamera.transform.LookAt(this.m_SimulateToObject.transform, Vector3.up);
                this.m_IsTargetInitiallyVisible = true; 
            }
            else if(this.m_SimulateCamera)
            {
                if(mo.getDistance() >= 10.0f)
                {
                    this.m_SimulateCamera = false;
                }
                mo.setDistance(-0.001f);
            }
        }

        if(!this.m_SimulateCamera)
        {               
                this.m_SimulationTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            this.m_SimulationTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(TriggerSimulatedPluck);
            this.m_SimulationTimer.Interval=2000;
            this.m_SimulationTimer.Enabled=true;
        }
    }

    void TriggerSimulatedPluck(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Enabled = false;
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Dispose();
        this.m_AutoPluck = true;
    }

    void AutoPluck()
    {
        System.Random random = new System.Random();
        GameObject mainCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag ("MainCamera");              
        MouseOrbit mo = null;   
        float applyForce = 0.0f;
        float slope = 0.00028648399272739457f;
        float y_int = 0.2908366193449838f;
        Vector3 vTorque = Vector3.zero;
        int simulateId = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SimulatePlayer" + this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].name);
        int seed = (5 * ((int)(SimulationOptions.Pro) - simulateId));
        int xSeed = 0;
        int ySeed = 0;
        int zSeed = 0;
        int sign = random.Next(1, 1000)%2;
        int range = random.Next(1, 1000)%seed;
        int myValue = 0;

        this.m_SimulationTimer.Enabled = false;
        this.m_SimulationTimer.Dispose();

        if(mainCamera)
        {
            mo = mainCamera.GetComponent<MouseOrbit>();
            mo.IsManualMove = false;
        }

        this.m_AutoPluck = false;

        if(simulateId >= 1)
        {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].transform.position,
                this.m_SimulateToObject.transform.position);

            if(simulateId != (int)(SimulationOptions.Pro))
            {
                myValue = random.Next(1, 6);
                seed = (int)(myValue * ((int)(SimulationOptions.Pro) - simulateId));
                sign = random.Next(1, 2);
                range = random.Next(1, seed);

                if(random.Next(1, 1000)%3 == 0)
                {
                    distance += (sign == 1 ? range : -range);
                }
            }

            vTorque.x = (float)(random.Next(1, 90));
            vTorque.y = (float)(random.Next(1, 90));
            vTorque.z = (float)(random.Next(1, 90));

            applyForce = (slope * distance) + y_int;
            this.m_Dispatcher.pluckObject(applyForce, vTorque);
        }
    }

    void determineTurnOutcome()
    {
        int number = -1;
        bool canActivePlayerContinue = false;
        bool isAutoReward = false;
        bool didElinimatePlayer = false;

        foreach(GameObject nextObject in this.m_Players)
        {
            PlayerCollisionDispatcher nextDispatcher = nextObject.GetComponent<PlayerCollisionDispatcher>();

            if(nextObject.activeSelf && !nextDispatcher.isGameOver && !nextDispatcher.isActive)
            {
                if(nextDispatcher.currentScore == nextDispatcher.targetScore)
                {
                    nextDispatcher.totalScore = nextDispatcher.targetScore;
                    int.TryParse(nextDispatcher.name, out number);
                    nextDispatcher.targetScore++;

                    if(nextDispatcher.totalScore >= 13 || nextDispatcher.targetScore > 13)
                    {
                        nextDispatcher.totalScore = 13;
                        nextDispatcher.targetScore = 13;
                        nextDispatcher.isKiller = true;
                        this.setMaterial(nextDispatcher.renderer, "killers", nextDispatcher.name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.setMaterial(nextDispatcher.renderer, "numbers", nextDispatcher.name);
                    }
                }
                else if(nextDispatcher.didKillerCollide && (nextDispatcher.didLeaveBoard || nextDispatcher.didLeaveBounds))
                {
                    this.setMaterial(nextDispatcher.renderer, "eliminated", nextDispatcher.name);
                    nextDispatcher.isGameOver = true;
                    didElinimatePlayer = true;
                }
                else if(nextDispatcher.didPlayerCollide && (nextDispatcher.didLeaveBoard || nextDispatcher.didLeaveBounds))
                {
                    if(int.TryParse(nextDispatcher.name, out number))
                    {
                        nextDispatcher.targetScore = 1;
                        nextDispatcher.totalScore = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if(nextDispatcher.didEnterMud)
                {
                    this.setMaterial(nextDispatcher.renderer, "mudd", nextDispatcher.name);
                    nextDispatcher.isKiller = false;
                }
                else if(nextDispatcher.isInMud && !nextDispatcher.didEnterMud)
                {
                    isAutoReward = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.setMaterial(nextDispatcher.renderer, "numbers", nextDispatcher.name);
                }
            }

            nextDispatcher.transferStates();
        }

        if(this.m_Dispatcher.isKiller && !didElinimatePlayer)
        {
            this.setMaterial(this.m_Dispatcher.renderer, "numbers", this.m_Dispatcher.name);
            this.m_Dispatcher.totalScore = 0;
            this.m_Dispatcher.targetScore = 1;
            this.m_Dispatcher.isKiller = false;
        }
        else if(this.m_Dispatcher.didEnterMud)
        {
            this.setMaterial(this.m_Dispatcher.renderer, "mud", this.m_Dispatcher.name);
        }

        else if(this.m_Dispatcher.currentScore == this.m_Dispatcher.targetScore || isAutoReward)
        {
            this.m_Dispatcher.totalScore = this.m_Dispatcher.targetScore;
            canActivePlayerContinue = true;
            this.m_Dispatcher.consecutivePops++;
            int.TryParse(this.m_Dispatcher.name, out number);
            this.m_Dispatcher.targetScore++;
            this.setMaterial(this.m_Dispatcher.renderer, "numbers", this.m_Dispatcher.name);
        }
        else
        {
            this.setMaterial(this.m_Dispatcher.renderer, "numbers", this.m_Dispatcher.name);
        }

        this.isWinnerAnnounced();

        if(!this.m_IsGameOver && !canActivePlayerContinue)
        {
            this.m_Dispatcher.endTurn();
            this.startNextPlayer();
        }
        else if(canActivePlayerContinue)
        {
            this.m_Dispatcher.transferStates();
            this.m_Dispatcher.isActive = true;
            this.m_Dispatcher.didObjectMove = false;
            this.m_Dispatcher.didObjectStop = false;

            if(this.m_IsSimulating >= 1)
            {           
                this.StartSimulation();
            }
        }

        this.m_ForceValue = 0.0f;   
    }

    void isWinnerAnnounced()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int totalPlayers = 0;
        string winner = string.Empty;
        int number = -1;
        int totalPlayersInMud = 0;

        foreach(GameObject nextObject in this.m_Players)
        {
            PlayerCollisionDispatcher nextDispatcher = nextObject.GetComponent<PlayerCollisionDispatcher>();

            if(!nextDispatcher.isGameOver)
            {
                totalPlayers++;
                winner = nextObject.name;
            }
            if(nextDispatcher.isInMud)
            {
                totalPlayersInMud++;
            }
        }

        if(totalPlayers == 1)
        {
            if(winner != string.Empty && int.TryParse(winner, out number))
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("Congratulations Player {0}", number);
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("WinningPlayer", sb.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("WinningPlayer", "Congratulations");
            }
            this.m_IsGameOver = true;
        }
        else if(totalPlayersInMud == this.m_Players.Count)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("WinningPlayer", "All players are stuck in the mud!");
            this.m_IsGameOver = true;
        }
    }

    void setMaterial(Renderer renderer, string state, string playerId)
    {
        StringBuilder sbNextImage = new StringBuilder();

        sbNextImage.AppendFormat("Materials/playerObjects/{0}/{1}", state, playerId);

        Material newMat = Resources.Load(sbNextImage.ToString(), typeof(Material)) as Material;
        if(newMat)
        {
            renderer.material = newMat;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("FAILED to set material: " + sbNextImage.ToString());
        }
    }

    void setAnnouncement(string text)
    {
        this.m_IsAnnouncement = true;
        this.m_AnnouncementHeight = (int)(Screen.height * 0.5);
        this.m_AnnouncementText = text;
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        GUIStyle labelStyle = GUI.skin.label;
        int number = -1;
        StringBuilder scoreDetails = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder turnDetails = new StringBuilder();
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        float w = 64.0f;
        float h = 32.0f;
        float alpha = 1.0f;

        if(this.m_IsAnnouncement)
        {
            this.displayAnnouncement();
        }

        labelStyle.normal.textColor = new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha);

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(32, 32, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {
                texture.SetPixel(i, j, new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f));
            }
        }

        texture.Apply();
        labelStyle.normal.background = texture;

        if(this.m_DoShowScore)
        {
            foreach(GameObject nextObject in this.m_Players)
            {
                PlayerCollisionDispatcher nextDispatcher = nextObject.GetComponent<PlayerCollisionDispatcher>();

                int.TryParse(nextDispatcher.name, out number);

                if(nextDispatcher.isGameOver)
                {
                    scoreDetails.AppendFormat("\tPlayer {0}: Game Over\n", number);
                }
                else if(nextDispatcher.didEnterMud)
                {
                    scoreDetails.AppendFormat("\tPlayer {0}: In The Mudd\n", number);
                }
                else if(nextDispatcher.isKiller)
                {
                    scoreDetails.AppendFormat("\tPlayer {0}: Killer\n", number);
                }
                else
                {
                    scoreDetails.AppendFormat("\tPlayer {0}: {1}\n", number, nextDispatcher.totalScore);
                }
            }                   

            GUI.Label (new Rect (0, 0, 225, 100), scoreDetails.ToString());
        }

        w = 64.0f;
        h = 32.0f;
        x = Screen.width - w;
        y = Screen.height - h;
        if(GUI.Button (new Rect (x, y, w, h), "Menu"))
        {
            audioPlayer.PlayAudio("Audio/Click");
            this.m_IsMenuShowing = !this.m_IsMenuShowing;
        }

        if(this.m_IsMenuShowing)
        {
                w = (64.0f * this.m_MenuText.Length);
            h = 32.0f;
            x = Screen.width - w - 64.0f;
            y = Screen.height - h;
            int selOption = GUI.Toolbar(new Rect(x, y, w, h), this.m_MenuOption, this.m_MenuText);

            if(selOption != this.m_MenuOption)
            {
                audioPlayer.PlayAudio("Audio/Click");
                this.m_MenuOption = -1;
                this.m_IsMenuShowing = !this.m_IsMenuShowing;
                switch(selOption)
                {                           
                case (int)(MenuOptions.ArialViewOption):    //arial
                    this.m_ArialCamera.SetActive(!this.m_ArialCamera.activeSelf);
                    break;
                case (int)(MenuOptions.VolumeOption):   //mute
                    int muteVolume = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MuteVolume");
                    muteVolume = (muteVolume + 1)%2;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MuteVolume", muteVolume);
                    if(muteVolume == 0)
                    {
                        this.m_MenuText[(int)(MenuOptions.VolumeOption)] = "Mute";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.m_MenuText[(int)(MenuOptions.VolumeOption)] = "Volume";
                    }
                    break;
                case (int)(MenuOptions.PauseOption):    //pause
                    if(Time.timeScale == 0.0f)
                    {
                        this.setAnnouncement("Continuing Game Play");
                        Time.timeScale = this.m_Speed;
                        this.m_MenuText[(int)(MenuOptions.PauseOption)] = "Pause";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.setAnnouncement("Game Is Paused");
                        Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
                        this.m_MenuText[(int)(MenuOptions.PauseOption)] = "Play";
                    }
                    break;
                case (int)(MenuOptions.ScoresOption):   //scores
                    this.m_DoShowScore = !this.m_DoShowScore;
                    break;
                case (int)(MenuOptions.RestartOption):  //restart
                    Time.timeScale = this.m_Speed;
                    this.restartGame();
                    break;
                case (int)(MenuOptions.QuitOption): //quit
                    Application.LoadLevel("Opening Screen");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(this.m_ArialCamera.activeSelf)
        {
            x = Screen.width * 0.7f - 10.0f;
            y = 0;
            w = 10.0f;
            h = Screen.height * 0.3f;
            this.m_ArialView.z = GUI.VerticalSlider (new Rect(x, y, w, h), this.m_ArialView.z, 1.0f, 0.0f);

            x = Screen.width * 0.7f;
            y = Screen.height * 0.3f;
            w = Screen.width * 0.3f;
            h = 10.0f;
            this.m_ArialView.x = GUI.HorizontalSlider (new Rect(x, y, w, h), this.m_ArialView.x, 1.0f, 0.0f);

            x = Screen.width * 0.7f;
            y = Screen.height * 0.3f + 12.0f;
            w = Screen.width * 0.3f;
            h = 10.0f;
            this.m_ArialView.y = GUI.HorizontalSlider (new Rect(x, y, w, h), this.m_ArialView.y, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        int.TryParse(this.m_Players[this.m_PlayerIndex].name, out number);

        turnDetails.AppendFormat("\tPlayer {0}'s Turn\n", number); 
        turnDetails.AppendFormat("\tNext Goal: {0}\n", this.m_Dispatcher.targetScore); 

        GUI.Label (new Rect (0, Screen.height - 100, 225, 100), turnDetails.ToString());

        if(!this.m_Dispatcher.didObjectMove && m_IsSimulating == 0)
        {
            x = 250.0f;
            y = Screen.height - 190.0f;
            w = 30.0f;
            h = 150.0f;
            this.m_ForceValue = GUI.VerticalSlider (new Rect(x, y, w, h), m_ForceValue, 1.0f, 0.0f);

            x = 250.0f;
            y = Screen.height - 30.0f;
            w = 100.0f;
            h = 30.0f;
            if(GUI.Button (new Rect(x, y, w, h), "Pluck!")) 
            {
                System.Random random = new System.Random();
                Vector3 vTorque = Vector3.zero;
                int xSeed = 0;
                int ySeed = 0;
                int zSeed = 0;

                xSeed = (random.Next(1, 45));
                ySeed = (random.Next(1, 45));
                zSeed = (random.Next(1, 45));

                vTorque = new Vector3(xSeed, ySeed, zSeed);
                this.m_Dispatcher.pluckObject(this.m_ForceValue, vTorque);
            }
        }   
    }   

    void displayAnnouncement()
    {
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        float w = 0;
        float h = 0;
        float alpha = 1.0f;     
        GUIStyle announcementStyle = null;
        GUIStyle labelStyle = null;

        announcementStyle = new GUIStyle();
        labelStyle = GUI.skin.label;
        labelStyle.normal.textColor = new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha);

        x = (int)(Screen.width * 0.25);
        y = (int)m_AnnouncementHeight;
        w = (int)(Screen.width * 0.5);
        h = 100;
        alpha = (float)m_AnnouncementHeight/(float)(Screen.height * 0.5);
        announcementStyle.fontSize = 32;
        announcementStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        announcementStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.BoldAndItalic;
        announcementStyle.normal.textColor = new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha);                

        GUI.Label (new Rect (x, y, w, h), this.m_AnnouncementText, announcementStyle);

        if(Time.timeScale != 0.0f)
        {
            if((this.m_AnnouncementHeight + h) <= 0)
            {
                this.m_IsAnnouncement = false;
                this.m_AnnouncementHeight = (int)(Screen.height * 0.5);
            }
            else
            {
                this.m_AnnouncementHeight -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

-----------
```

Comment: Even if OnGUI method are not the best for what concern performances, I don't think they are them to freeze your pc. Anyway, have you tried to comment out them in order to confirm your suspects?

Comment: You need to narrow it down as @Heisenbug suggests, otherwise we're taking guesses in the dark.  But you say it's freezing the whole computer? Did you just mean the app freezes or the whole computer?  As an FYI, I have a test app w/ around 40 controls rendered at the same time, no issues.

Comment: I'm grateful for your responses. I have commented my source code, but I troubleshooting an issue related to the camera. Jerak: Yes. the entire computer, minus the mouse cursor, is freezing. The script that I have written to control the game (913 lines of code). It seems to be straightforward, but we never know. 

There's a second script that I've inherited that allows users to navigate across the terrain.

Comment: Nothing obvious jumps out from your description of the problem.  Without seeing the actual code the best any of us can say is that you need to do more debugging on your own to isolate the problem.

Comment: @Heisenbug: The only object that remains is my gamePlayController object. I see that the methods Update(), FixedUpdate, LateUpdate(), and OnGUI() will most often be called. The OnCollisionEnter() and OnCollisionExit() also gets called a lot. I've posted a lot of source code below. I do appreciate your insight in advance.

Comment: @Jerdak: You're included, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it...

My initial suspicions were correct: the problem did lie within the OnGUI() method. I moved the following source code to the Start() method. It made sense, since I'm only building a transparent background texture once.:

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(32, 32, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {
        texture.SetPixel(i, j, new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f));
    }
}

texture.Apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have narrowed the freezing down. Simulated testing results is leading me to believe that my problem is inside the OnGUI() method. I have commented that method out all together, and my app is operating smoothly. I'll figure this out, unless someone beats me to the root cause and solution.